# State not updating in React when setting new value

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble updating the state after using put to update the value

```
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

  const sortBlogs = (blogs) =>
    [...blogs].sort((a, b) => Number(b.likes) - Number(a.likes));

  const handleLike = async (id) => {
    console.log(blogs[1].likes);
    const response = await blogApi.likeBlog(user, id);
    console.log(response.data.likes);
    let sorted = sortBlogs(
      [...blogs].filter((blog) => blog.id !== id).concat(response.data)
    );
    console.log(sorted[1].likes);
    setBlogs(sorted);
    console.log(blogs[1].likes);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    blogService.getAll().then((blogs) => setBlogs(sortBlogs(blogs)));
  }, []);
```

everything works up to the part which is setBlogs the value it is given is correct however it does not fire or something but basically the value is not updated.

I have console-logged everything with the api, the sorting, the filtering, and the value that setBlogs is being handed over and everything is correct however blogs are not being updated by it...

console.log outputs:

```
71
72
72
71
```

I have tried using a function that would be called by the async function to see if the update was not happening because of a state being changed by async.

I have tried restructuring the function in various ways.

I have tried first setting it to the filtered array without the new entry and then adding it, it added it without removing the previous one.

I have tried creating a refresh function using state and then setting it to true to force a react refresh by setting the state to true and using useEffect to set it back to false.

Comment: Where is `handleLike` being called?

Comment: @peperoli it is being passed as a prop to a child component and called from there.

Answer (score 0):

It started working after restarting Vite.

This is my code now, basically the same but it works now.

```
  const handleLike = async (id) => {
    const response = await blogApi.likeBlog(user, id);
    setBlogs(
      sortBlogs(
        [...blogs].filter((blog) => blog.id !== id).concat(response.data)
      )
    );
  };
```

Everything else is the same.